# What is the word for something close to you in a way that you want to have it?

Tags: single-word-requests

Something that is conveniently close to you that makes you want to have it. 
Example: the apple in the tree was ****ly close to me.

I just cannot remember the word. It is something along "tentatively" or "tenacious".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you thinking of "tantalisingly"?

> tantalising - Tormenting or teasing with the sight or promise of something unobtainable.
>
> ‘a tantalizing glimpse of the career he might have had’

(Oxford English Dictionary)

Comment: YEESSSS You are a genius! Damn, that illusive word. THANKS.